# How SBT resolves conflicted version of libraries in dependency

Tags: scala, dependencies, sbt

I have the following situation:

```
+ Module A
   L Library 1.0


+ Module B
   L Module A
   L Library 2.0
```

Suppose there is no interface change between `Library 1.0` and `Library 2.0`.

Now, when I import the library in a class belonging to `Module B` which version will be imported? Any reference to useful resources will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run `sbt` it should print warnings like:

```
[warn] Found version conflict(s) in library dependencies; some are suspected to be binary incompatible:
[warn]  * org.scala-js:sbt-scalajs:0.6.22 is selected over {0.6.19, 0.6.21}
[warn]      +- default:scala-adapters-form-build:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0) (depends on 0.6.21)
[warn]      +- org.scala-native:sbt-scalajs-crossproject:0.2.2 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0) (depends on 0.6.19)
```

If it takes the one you want and you can live with the warnings your done.

Otherwise you have to exclude transitive dependencies.

All of this is described here: **[sbt manual](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Library-Management.html#Conflict+Management)**